# Receiving PDNS NOTIFY for domain I no longer host

Tags: cluster, powerdns

On a couple of my servers in a DNS cluster running CloudLinux and PowerDNS, I've been receiving the following in my LFD Log Scanner Reports:

```
pdns[2569215]: Received NOTIFY for example.com from 54.39.100.160 but slave support is disabled in the configuration
```

(*I've replaced the actual domain with example.com in the above line*)

However - the notice is for a domain that I terminated from the server a long time ago and is no longer hosted by me.

I can see that the IP address in the notice is from a server not in my network or data center. It is the host that the client migrated their website to before I terminated the account from my server.

I've spent a lot of time searching, reading docs and various forums, and can't seem to find out how / why this would be happening.

Does anyone know why this would happen?

Thank you.

Comment: As there can be multiple reasons for the issue, have you ensured that the domain has been migrated cleanly? Have you checked if the DNS matches the new settings? In the past, when I used to run a hosting business, some difficult customers had to learn the hard way. To solve this issue quickly, I recreated the domain and set the response to 127.0.0.1. However, generally, I don't pay much attention to such issues since I still encounter some buggy DNS servers that don't seem to respect the new settings.

Comment: @djdomi - thank you for the reply. I can no longer reach the original webmaster, the site/domain migrated cleanly many months ago. Looking up their domain and DNS on resources like securitytrails.com intodns.com mxtoolbox.com all show that there is nothing in their DNS referring to mine at all. All looks correct, and their site / email services all correctly resolve to their new home.  No sign of the domain in /var/cpanel/moddirdomains on my servers either. Entries in /var/log/messages are not coming from my servers or cluster either. It's external.

Comment: Sorry but the usual administration does not apply on offtopic administration panel, you might check if it is always the same ip quering this domain. if yes then you can just set in bind9 to ignore the ips, if different, the only way would be to re-create the dns-entry and put the correct dns settings inside for some month and then retest it. i still get queries for my old domains on my old server where dns was hosted in the past.